# PHP sqlsrv in Zend server 8

Tags: sql-server

I have Zend Server Version: 6.1.0 running PHP Version 5.4.16, I want to migrate my scripts to a new server : Zend Server Version: 8.0.2 PHP Version 5.6.5

```
$link = mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$query = 'some valid SQL';
```

On my OLD server, this code : **mssql_query($query, $link);** returns data.  I use this code extensively, and it ALWAYS returns data.

On my NEW server it returns "Warning: mssql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean" and then fails

Every time I google, I get "do you mean MYSQL?" please can someone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Please provide your query and `SQL Server` version (`SELECT @@version`)

Comment: There are 6 SQL servers of various flavours  
  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)  
  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5538.0 (Intel X86)  
  Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)  
  
A sample query :  
$connector = new dbconnector();  
$mySQL = 'select DeptCode, DeptName from DC_Departments order by DeptCode';  
$result = $connector->query($mySQL) or die (dumpSQL($mySQL).'Query failed.');  
  
If I run this query on server one I get a lovely department list, on server two I get the error

Comment: Please provide a real error message... why query failed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Warning: mssql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in "path to server"\assets\includes\class_sqldbconnector.php on line 45  
  
  
select DeptCode, DeptName from DC_Departments order by DeptCode Query failed.

Comment: function query($query) {
       $this->theQuery = $query;
       return mssql_query($query, $this->link);
       }